# How to use Global module in NestJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I am using nest js for  back-end. For this project i started to use NestJs, and in the documentation i found that in nestJs we can build `Global Modules`. So my global module looks like this:

```js
//Module
import {Global, Module} from "@nestjs/common";
import {GlobalController} from "./global.controller";
import {GlobalService} from "./global.service";
@Global()
@Module({
  imports:[],
  exports:[GlobalService],
  providers:[GlobalService],
  controllers:[GlobalController]
})
export class GlobalModule {}
```

```js
//Controller
import { Controller, Get } from "@nestjs/common";
import {GlobalService} from "./global.service";
@Controller()

export class GlobalController {
    constructor(private readonly getGlobalData: GlobalService) {
    }
    @Get('global')
    getGlobal(){
        return this.getGlobalData.getGlobalData()
    }
}
```

```js
//Service
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
@Injectable()
export class GlobalService {
    private readonly global = [1,12,2]
    getGlobalData(){
     return this.global.map(d => d)
    }
}
```

In my root module i registered my global module:

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import {GlobalModule} from "./globalModule/global.module";

@Module({
  imports: [GlobalModule], //register global module
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Now the module is working, and when i go to `..../global` i get my data from `global` array.
How i understand we can create global module to avoid repeating the same code in each module.

**Question:**  According to my example how can i use my global module in different modules?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Globle module without import not working nestjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70064235/globle-module-without-import-not-working-nestjs)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use that GlobalModule on other module you must import that module on your **root module** like this:

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { OtherModule } from "./otherModule/other.module";
import { GlobalModule } from "./globalModule/global.module";

@Module({
  imports: [GlobalModule, OtherModule], //Import the other module
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Then in your other module you will be able to use the GlobalService without importing the GlobalModule, this is very useful when you need to use a service inside a Guard easily.

Comment: What are the cons of doing this ... if any?

Comment: No one (I think) but making everything global is a bad practice, just use it only when it's needed.

Comment: @VisakhVijayan Hint from the official documentation: Making everything global is not a good design decision. Global modules are available to reduce the amount of necessary boilerplate. The imports array is generally the preferred way to make the module's API available to consumers.

Comment: I agree @szeb. I use it when a module is being shared across a number of modules.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to use some service of high frequency (such as  prisam,jwt,redis,bull et al), you can just :

1. put these all service in a globalModule
2. registed globalModule in root module
3. use these services in any other module without import global module again and again.